# Simple division in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

Trying to achieve the PanelSoldMonths rate using PanelSoldDays and DateDaysInMonth. However, I am getting a return of nulls when doing this simple division.

PanelSoldMonths = PanelSoldDays  / DateDaysInMonth

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].PanelSoldMonths AS 
IIF ([In Charge Date].[In Charge Date Days in Month]= 0, NULL,
     ([Measures].[Panel Sold Days] / [In Charge Date].[In Charge Date Days in Month].Children))
    SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Total Net Net Revenue], [Measures].[Panel Sold Days], [Measures].PanelSoldMonths}
ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY
    ([In Charge Date].[In Charge Year].Children,  [In Charge Date].[In Charge Date Days in Month].Children)
ON ROWS
    FROM [Combined Sales]
    WHERE [Asset Info].[Format Group L2].&[Digital]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
[In Charge Date].[In Charge Date Days in Month]= 0
```

with

```
[In Charge Date].[In Charge Date Days in Month].currentmember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED)=0
```

Comment: returns an #Error

Comment: double click, and share what is the error details.

Comment: Moved away from this approach . Can you have a look at this latest question I have posted. I am new to the world of MDX. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673136/converting-mdx-query-into-ssas-cube-expression-calculations